# Convenient way to drop empty strings from a collection

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, linq

I am looking for a convenient way to drop list items with empty string as their value.

I know I could check each string to see if it is empty before loading into the list.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(someString))
{
    items.Add(someString);
}
```

However, this seems a bit cumbersome especially if I have a lot of strings to add to the list.

Alternatively, I could just load all the strings regardless of being empty or not:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
items.Add("one");
items.Add("");
items.Add("two")
```

Then iterate over the list and if an empty string is found remove it.

```
foreach (string item in items)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
    {
        items.Remove(item);
    }              
}
```

Are these my only two options, perhaps there is something in Linq?

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Why do you think it's cumbersome to check for an empty string before adding it? If you are creating this list, then you have full control over what goes into it - why filter it after the fact?

Comment: The trouble with removing empty elements later on is that `.Remove` forces copying all elements that follow the element to be removed one index position downwards. So, with lots of strings you're better off creating a new list without those empty elements. However, then why shouldn't those empty elements left out at all?

Comment: @ChrisMcAtackney So would I end up with something like this:

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(string1))
    items.Add(string1);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(string2))
    items.Add(string2);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(string3))
    items.Add(string3);

Or is there a more graceful way I am missing?

Comment: Use a method: AddString(IList aList, String aString)

Comment: @JeffRSon Is this what you are suggesting: http://pastebin.com/A5cBraQL

I can't make the List a class variable.

Comment: Yes, though you should call addString like `addString(items, string1)` a.s.o. Such you don't need a class variable for the list. Also you may want to use `IList` for the first parameter for the method to be used more flexible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
 items.RemoveAll(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Or you can filter them out using `where`:

```
var noEmptyStrings = items.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Comment: You could even remove the lambda syntax in this case since the types already match: `items.RemoveAll(String.IsNullOrEmpty);`

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to Darren's answer you could use an extension method :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the provided collection of strings without any empty strings.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="items">The collection to filter</param>
    /// <returns>The collection without any empty strings.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<string> RemoveEmpty(this IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        return items.Where(i => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i));
    }
```

And Then usage :

```
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add("Foo");
        items.Add("");
        items.Add("Bar");

        var nonEmpty = items.RemoveEmpty();
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking strings before adding them to your list will always be less cumbersome than deleting them from the list or creating a whole new one. You're trying to avoid string comparison (checking its emptyness actually, which is executed really fast) and replace it by list copying, which will have a strong impact on your app's performance. If you only can check strings before adding them to list - do so, and don't compound.

Comment: Good point but what if the creation of the collection is done by code that is not under your control?

Comment: Of course he should use a method proposed above if he can't control adding items to list, but read the last sentence of mine please. Also - he said he could check strings before adding them to list, but didn't want to, because it's "cumbersome".

Comment: @Tarec Would you use something like this instead: http://pastebin.com/A5cBraQL or is there a more graceful way to check before adding?  (I can't make the List a class variable)

Comment: I don't know why do you think your method is bad :) It's easy, clean and does exactly what need. I don't recall any built in methods in .NET that'd help you. If you want it to be even more graceful and hide somehow the code, you could always write your own extension method for List class, but IMO it's an exaggeration.